# dividing Mean by standard Deviation meaning

Tags: regression, statistics, logistic-regression, variance, mean

I have played around with logistic regression a little using movement data intervals that are prelabeled as either resting or active.
I now found that if I divide the mean movement of the individual intervals by the intervals standard deviation, the outcome is quite a good predictor of whether the interval is a resting interval or or active, with an average auc = 0.93 in a 20 fold cross validation.

Does someone have an idea of what I have created dividing the mean by the standard deviation? Its like a flipped coefficient of variation, or semi-normalization?!.

I want to report this in an essay, so I am asking myself whether there is a name to this statistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created what can be called a *normalised mean*. *Normalised* in the sense that it corresponds to a related random variable which now has $\sigma = 1$ (since you divide by standard deviation, look it up in any [statistics textbook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)#Examples)).

The normalised mean can be a better predictor resulting from its normalisation which makes it robust to the range of fluctuations.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. That makes a lot of sense.